# SearchView android became Search Application?

Tags: android, searchview

I don't know why searchView become search Application in Lenovo phone [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SsNT7.png). Although my code just in my app, anyone can help. Thank so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think in Lenovo phone they Override SearchView framework of Android. Therefore it searches application. I solve this problem by use another search, thank for this library [library search material](https://github.com/lapism/SearchView). This library use EditText replaces SearchView and it is great to use.